# Beginner Calculator - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

It's my first project with ReactJS, 
I'm trying to make my first app - calculator. 
Now in my project I should see all digits and operator which I wrote in code but I can't see them. Where did I make mistake? 
I have no idea why it's not working.
I have to write some more details in that question so I will write this sentences to make more text in that question!

My project:

```js
 var Calculator = React.createClass({

    getInitialState:function(){
      return {
        math:[
          ["C","/","*","-"],
          [7,8,9,"+"],
          [4,5,6,"+"],
          [1,2,3,"="],
          [0,".","="]
        ]
      }
    },

    render:function(){
      return (
          <div id="calculator"> 
          <div id="result"></div>
          <div id="mathtable">
            {this.state.math.map(function(row){
              var mutants = row.map(function(operand){
                return (
                  <div className="numoperam" >{operand}</div>
                )
              })
              return (
                <div className="rows" >
                  {mutants}
                  </div>
              )
            })}
      </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  })

  ReactDOM.render(<Calculator/>,document.getElementById("space"))
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
  background: blue;
  font-family: "Roboto";
}

#space {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin-left: 25vw;
  background: red;
}

#calculator {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#calculator>div {
  width: 100%;
}

#result {
  height: 20vh;
}

#mathtable {
  height: 60vh;
}

.rows {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}

.rows>div {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}

.numoperam {}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="space"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: `mutants` is an array (the result of the `map`). Perhaps try using `<div className="rows">{mutants.join('')}</div>` - see if that works.

Comment: @Andy array of ReactNode. So that is not the issue

Comment: nothing changed :(

Comment: @Piotr can you please explain, what exactly do you mean *but I can't see them.* Nodes are visible in snippet.

Comment: https://codepen.io/f0kusek/pen/Rjgmwm

Comment: @Piotr if you open dev console, it says *React is not defined.* You are not loading scripts related to React. If you load it, it will work. You can check snippet for sample.

Comment: Thanks, it works :)